# Hidden not working with Array in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'm trying to hide an image using `[hidden]` attribute using an array element, but its giving template parse error.

```
<img id="ProfilePictureResize_{{i}}" [hidden]="!{{temporarySubCategoryImageShow[i]}}" src="{{temporarySubCategoryImageUrl[i]}}"/>
```

But when I try `[hidden]` with `boolean` variable it works fine.

```
<img id="ProfilePictureResize_{{i}}" [hidden]="!isPreviewImage" src="{{temporarySubCategoryImageUrl[i]}}"/>
```

**TS File:**

```
public temporarySubCategoryImageShow: string[] = [];
private isPreviewImage: boolean = false;
```

**Error Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: remove the `{{    }}` and just put in the variable as normal like so - `temporarySubCategoryImageShow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the interpolation `"{{}}"` in `[hidden]` attribute

```
 [hidden]="!temporarySubCategoryImageShow[i]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remove the interpolation from the `hidden` attribute.

```
[hidden]="!temporarySubCategoryImageUrl[i]"
```

Comment: if the error message is clear, then you're not reading it properly because that's not what it's saying.

Comment: @DavidAnthonyAcosta `Got interpolation where expression was expected` seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: he modified his original comment. Originally he said it was SRC attribute, which is not what the message says